# Using regular expressions to locate line comments without spaces

Tags: regex

I tried to find all comments beginning with `//` that don't have a space after the slashes.
I want to select *only* the slashes. No whitespace or text before that, no whitespace or text after that.
So far I've reached to `[\s].(\/\/(?! ))` but it catches the space before the slashes as well.

Basically I wanna make sure my line comments have a space after the slashes.
I'm trying to do this either in JavaScript or in any text editor.

Comment: *I tried to find all comments beginning with `//` that don't have a space after the slashes.* and *I wanna make sure my line comments have a space after the slashes.* contradict each other. Please post sample strings that you want to match and that you do not want to match. To match line comments without spaces, I'd use `/\/\/\S+$/` or `/\/\/(?:(?!\/\/)\S)*$/`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU2qY6/1).

Comment: So why you're using `[\s].`?

Comment: @Kasramvd I guess that it is to find any spaces/tab before the comment, that are indented. I guess.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Maybe but it's wrong anyway.

Comment: What if you try this: `/^[\/]{2}[^\s].+/g`?

Comment: @sehrob: even if you put a slash in a character class, this one isn't escaped when you use the literal notation.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew they don't contradict with each other. The first one is what I'm looking for, the second one is my end goal. Your examples match the rest of the line while I only want to select the slashes.  
@Kasramvd to avoid selecting things like ``http://`` or semicolons in statements like ``return true; // comment``.

Comment: @sehrob this doesn't work if the comment isn't at the beginning of the line

Comment: Then try `(?<!\S)\/\/(?!.* )` - this will ensure there is no non-whitespace right before the `//` and will make sure there is no space after the `//`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU2qY6/2). **What is your regex flavor? (tool, programming language?)**

Comment: Well then you can try this one: `/[\/]{2}[^\s].+/g`:)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew either javascript or any text editor would be nice.

Comment: My regex above will work in Notepad++ and SublimeText. For JS, you'd need to use capture groups and use something like `/(^|\s)(\/\/)(?!.* )/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewyour ``(?<!\S)\/\/(?!.* )`` works in NP++ but only if there's a single word after the slashes. It won't match ``//Test test``.

Comment: That is why I posted my first comment: what do you really want to achieve??? Seeing Casimirs answer is up voted, maybe you need `(?<!\S)\/\/(?! )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since javascript doesn't have the lookbehind feature, you can't.

The workaround (for instance, in a replacement context) is to use a capture group for the character before the two slashes and to start the replacement string with a reference to this group (`'$1replacement'`):

```
([^/\s]|^)//(?! )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

`.*(\/\/(?= ))` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL1yX1/1)

The idea is to use positive lookahead and capture the `//` iff it is followed by a space.

**EDIT:** Just noticed that your question is contradictory. So if you want to capture if the `//` is not followed by a space, use this: `.*(\/\/(?=\S))`. Otherwise use the one above.

Comment: This also captures any whitespace or text before the slashes. I only want the slashes.

Comment: @VergilPenkov No it does not. It *matches* the text before the slashes. The only capturing group *captures* just what you want. Mind giving an example?

Comment: ``http.setTimeout(30000); //30 secs`` is an example. Everything before and including the slashes gets selected using your second expression. Your first doesn't do that but it selects the whitespace before slashes (such as tabs or spaces) if there are any.

Comment: This is the case wherein the slashes are **not** followed by a space. So, if you use the second `regex` provided in the answer, it will capture `//` which can then be used via `\1`